# how do i get a logged in user from my database and render the users details on the html page

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

okay so i'm trying to get a logged in user's information after authenticating the user and the user's id and email are stored in a session so i'm trying to get the users email from the session and check if it is equal to any one in the database(mongodb) and output the user's information but it isn't working this is the code

```
router.post("/login", async function (req, res) {
  const userData = req.body;
  const enteredEmail = userData.userEmail;
  const enteredUserName = userData.userName;
  const enteredPassword = userData.password;

  let existingUser = await db
    .getDb()
    .collection("users")
    .findOne({ userEmail: enteredEmail });

  if (!existingUser) {
     req.session.userInputData = {
      hasError: true,
      message: "user does not exist",
      userEmail: enteredEmail,
      password: enteredPassword,
    };

    req.session.save(function () {
       res.redirect("/login");
    });
     return;
  }

  const passwordsAreEqual = await bcrypt.compare(
    enteredPassword,
    existingUser.password
  );

  if (!passwordsAreEqual) {
    req.session.userInputData = {
      hasError: true,
      message: "Invalid input - please check your credentials",
      userEmail: enteredEmail,
      password: enteredPassword,
    };

    req.session.save(function () {
       res.redirect("/login");
    });
     return;
   }

  req.session.user = { id: existingUser._id, email: existingUser.email };
  req.session.isAuthenticated = true;
   req.session.save(function () {
    res.redirect("/billing");
  });
});

router.get("/billing", async function (req, res) {
  if (!req.session.isAuthenticated) {
    return res.status(401).render("401");
  } else {
     const user = await db
      .getDb()
      .collection("users")
      .findOne({ userEmail: req.session.user.email });
  }
    res.render("billing", { user: user });
 });
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean in this context? An error, unexpected behavior (what?), something else?

Comment: it's not displaying the users information as expected. its just blank